# How to configure firewall on user defined Docker bridge?

Tags: firewall, docker, bridge

I created a user-defined bridge using the docker command:

```
docker network create --driver bridge mynetwork
```

This command resulted in a bridge being created, as shown by `netstat -i`:

```
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
br-000f1  1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMRU
```

In the same way that I previously trusted the `docker0` bridge, I need to add this new bridge to my firewall trust zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=Docker0
```

I don't see a way to infer or specify the bridge device name, so I'm not sure how I can add it to my trust zone in an automated way.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Until an answer can be found I am adding IP networks to my trust zone instead of link devices. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=172.16.0.0/12`

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on Marek's Answer of setting the bridge name at creation time.

```
docker network create --driver bridge -o \
  "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="mynetwork_name" mynetwork
```

or if using a docker-compose file the following in the networks section

```
version: '3'
  .
  .
  .
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: mynetwork_name
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the firewalld rule persistent with this approach, so it survives a reboot? The --permanent switch does not work, because the interface does not exist until you create it with docker-compose up (or on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

Docker has option to set a bridge name on creation time

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#bridge-driver-options

Comment: Please copy the important parts of the web site you linked into the answer. Links change or go dead frequently, and it would be best if this answer could continue to serve the community long after the link has died.